# How to programmaticaly (java) obtain JBoss info and manage it?

Tags: java, jboss

Hi i want to obtain from java classes infos on JBoss like the status and the version and then manage him by starting/stopping/resatring him.
For the version i do this :

```
String fileSeparator = System.getProperty("file.separator");

        String runJarFile = jbossHomeDir + fileSeparator + "bin" + fileSeparator + "run.jar";
        System.out.println("JBOSSDIR est :" + runJarFile);

        jarInputStream = new JarInputStream(new FileInputStream(runJarFile));

        System.out.println("Pigmalion" + jarInputStream.getNextEntry().getName());

        Manifest manifest = jarInputStream.getManifest();
        Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();

        jbossVersion = attributes.getValue(Attributes.Name.SPECIFICATION_VERSION);
```

which works fine, now for the status, i saw some people doing it by checking the port, but isn't there another way of doing it ?

As for the start/stop/restart commands i saw this script

```
package com.sudipta.jboss.conf;

import org.jboss.Main;

public class JbossOperation {
    public static Main ob;
    static Class jbossMain;
    static{
        try {
            jbossMain=Class.forName("org.jboss.Main");
            ob = (Main)jbossMain.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

/**
 * START JBOSS SERVER
 * @return true if started successfully
 */
public static boolean startServer(){
    boolean status=true;

    String str[]={"-c","default"};            
    try {
        ob.boot(str);

    } catch (Exception e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }        
    return status;
}

/**
 * STOP JBOSS SERVER
 * @return true if started successfully
 */
public static boolean stopServer(){
    boolean status=true;        
    try {
        ob.shutdown();            
    } catch (Throwable e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }                

    return status;
}

/**
 * Main method
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("---------------------Strating the server------------------");
    startServer();
    System.out.println("---------------------Stoping the server------------------");
    stopServer();
    System.out.println("---------------------SERVER STOPPED------------------");
}
```

}

I downloaded the jboss-system 4.0.2 jar and it tells me the shutdown method doesn't exist. Do i have to download other jboss jars ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something more enterprisy (but still open source). You may want to use [RHQ](http://www.jboss.org/rhq) for it. It allows to run operations on managed resources and it can start/restart/stop JBoss server, deploy a war to it and far more. But the learning curve may be quite steep.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to use JMX Console?. Moreover, if you really need to manage the server from a Java program you could write a JMX client that invoke specific server operations like shutdown. Additionaly, different kind of server information can be obtained this way. (ofcourse JMX wont be useful for start the server).

Comment: Do you have a good ans clear jmx tutorial as i really have zero experience on that

Comment: Already exists a JMX client called [Twiddle](https://github.com/swesource/twiddle-standalone) that could be useful. The [examples](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-script/twiddle-reference-guide) show how to use it throught a script but I think It should be posible to use the class org.jboss.console.twiddle.Twiddle directly in your program.